# El significado de "ni le van ni vienen al autor del hilo"

Tags: expresiones, significado-en-contexto

Una persona hizo un comentario sobre el hilo de la otra, diciendo que no va a responder a cosas que "ni le van ni vienen al autor del hilo". Quisiera saber qué quiso decir esa persona con "ni le van ni vienen al autor del hilo".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la entrada del verbo [**ir**](https://dle.rae.es/ir) en el DLE podemos encontrar la expresión

> no irle ni venirle a alguien algo, o no irle ni venirle a alguien nada
> en algo
>
> 1. locs. verbs. coloqs. No importarle, tenerle sin cuidado.

Si nos referimos a una tercera persona, él o ella, a la que no le importan varias cosas (plural) la [conjugación del verbo ir](https://dle.rae.es/ir#conjugacionfTI3cnW) empleada es: **van**

> Ni le van ni le vienen al autor del hilo = No le importan al autor del hilo

Answer (score 1):

Por ampliar la [respuesta de RubioRic](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/37499/12637), estoy viendo que en el diccionario de Covarrubias (1611) ya existía la definición de "irle algo a alguien" con el significado de "interesarle a alguien alguna cosa". Y de hecho, en el *Autoridades* (1734) ya se registra el uso combinado de los verbos *ir* y *venir* en negativo en la expresión que nos ocupa:

> Sin *irle* ni venirle. Phrase con que explicamos, que no le importa ò pertenece à alguno aquello de que trata.

El texto que el propio *Autoridades* cita a modo de ejemplo es de Quevedo:

> *Allí fue ello, que el compañero, viendo que andaban a pescuezo, le dio un pan como unas nueces, sin irle ni venirle.*
>
> Francisco de Quevedo y Villegas, "Cuento de cuentos", 1626 (España).

Así pues, efectivamente la expresión significa que algo no le importa a determinada persona, y se lleva usando al menos cuatro siglos que sepamos.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por su explicación!